# TFS: Search for a file by name in source control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, source-control-explorer

I can't find a file in our source control of the TFS because it's simply a big mess. So I want to know if there is a way to search for files by their name?

I've heard of the Power Tool for TFS which enables search functionality but the problem is that it has to be installed and our sysadmin is currently not available. So does maybe a simple plugin exist?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010

- Right click on your collection or team project
- Select 'Find in source control'
- Then select 'status' or 'wildcard'
- You can search for your files there

The following will list all the items in your repository without checking them out

[tf Dir command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6320xzye(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
tf dir /recursive $/
```

you can pass in the item you are searching for also e.g.

```
tf dir /recursive $/*.cs
```

gets all the .cs files in all team projects

Note: depending on how big your source is, this could take sometime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this only works with TFS Power Tools installed and as I said at the moment our sysadmin isn't available and so I can't install them to get these features.
But still thank you very much for trying to help! :)

Comment: @W1ese1 - the power toys go on you client machine not on the TFS Server - also the command line should work without the power toys.

Comment: The problem with the power tools is that I have to work on a remote desktop and therefore I haven't got the rights to install anything.

Seems like I have overseen the rest were you posted about the command line. I will check that out and if it works I'll mark your answer :)

Comment: Ok, I'd still need the power tools to be able to work with the tf command. But still thanks for your help.

Comment: tf.exe will be part of Visual Studio, TFPT.exe is the powertools executable. Make sure you launch it from a Visual Studio command Prompt.

Comment: I don't know why i am seeing it in Visual studio 2008 while not in VS2010

Comment: I also had to use the /server command line option, like as specified at [http://devatheart.com/2010/10/24/searching-for-a-file-in-team-foundation-server/](http://devatheart.com/2010/10/24/searching-for-a-file-in-team-foundation-server/).

Comment: Has this feature been added in VS 2015 IDE by default , or still we are dependent on power tools

Comment: Please add the following note: Works on Local workspaces, not available for Server workspaces

Comment: The "tf dir" command helped me.  also, adding a "> filename.txt" to the end will allow you to export the results to a file for further analysis or import into excel etc.

Comment: The "find by wildcard" feature was removed from VS2017 (I used to use it a lot on VS2015) for some stupid reason. You are left only with commandline.

Comment: If you try to wildcard the filename ($/*.cs) you now get: TF402396: You cannot include wildcard characters in a team project name.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a workspace on your local, then you can search a file in your local to get the path.

Comment: This works just fine as long as you don't have any cloaked dirs.

Comment: if you have a TFS collection with hundreds of projects this solution is not viable.  sure it works for finding a file in the current workspace, but the OP asked for searching a TFS collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Azure DevOps you can open the Azure Repos section in Azure DevOps for your project. There is a search input on this screen that allows you to search your code. You can find out more in Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/code-search?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

Combining WebPlanet's answer and this https://devatheart.com/2010/10/24/searching-for-a-file-in-team-foundation-server/

I got the following to work when searching for a .rdl file on my TFS server.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe" dir "$/*.rdl" /recursive /server:http://yourTFSserver
```

- In my case tfs.exe was in the VS 2017 location.
- http://yourTFSserver
  should be the path to the TFS server's web interface (including any port and path)