# How to find a file in TFS2012?

Tags: version-control, tfs, filenames, changeset

i know the file name (ex:xyz.cs, xyz.dll etc) dont know the changeset number, but which folder this files are available, it is big task to find the files in tfs2012, any easy way to search the file path?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS: Search for a file by name in source control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251695/tfs-search-for-a-file-by-name-in-source-control)

Answer (score 2):

After the [TFS2012 Power Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) is installed, it is possible for you to find with Wildcard.

Right-click the team project in the Source Control Explorer, select **Find** -> **Find by Wildcard**. Type the file name to locate that file.

[image]